# Pasting from SQL Server 2014 to Excel 2013

Tags: excel, t-sql, export, paste, sql-server-2014

My work machine was just upgraded to Excel 2013 add I can no longer paste results from SQL Server to Excel 2013. It just turns into a long text string that I can't break apart even with text to columns. I'm not sure if it's a setting in SQL Server or Excel, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Incidentally, a friend just stopped by an answered my question. I had been using a concatenation in another workbook and by shutting down excel completely that seem to have solved the problem.

Comment: If you think your question and it's answer might be helpful to others, please take some time to [detail it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise close the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the data by right clicking in the top left corner of the results window and selecting Select All, then selecting Copy With Headers, then pasting into Excel.

You can also Select All, then Save Results As and save it as a CSV file, then convert it to an Excel file.

The second option works best for me when the data set becomes more than a few hundred thousand rows/records.